# Simple way to disable Cellphone (data & call) without disabling WiFi & Bluetooth on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Airplane mode is fine sometimes - but sometimes I want a quick way to turn off my cell circuits (calls / sms / cell data) - without turning off WiFi & Bluetooth.

And no, I don't want to turn on Flight mode then re-enable Cell & Bluetooth (this is specifically not a duplicate of that question).

I may be playing music on a Bluetooth device, and connected to Wifi - turning those off and on can be extremely disruptive.

Are there any widgets that can do this say? You should be able to customise control centre to do it

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on airplane mode, then re-enabling Wi-Fi and Bluetooth is currently the only option.

You can send feedback to Apple [here](http://apple.com/feedback) about wanting the ability to turn of Cellular.

Answer (score -1):

I agree you should be able to customise the control centre.

What about keeping the sim card pin gadget on your keyring and popping out the SIM tray a little? Too risky?

Comment: lol nice idea but not really practical.